# Why does findall returns a blank string?

Tags: python, regex, findall

```
Pattern = re.compile('.*', re.DOTALL)
Pattern.findall('Serve the public trust.\nProtect the innocent.\nUphold the law.')
```

It returns an extra blank string in the end.

> Output = ['Serve the public trust.\nProtect the innocent.\nUphold the
> law.', '']

How can I prevent this?

Comment: You can use `.+` to match 1 or more times instead.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug in some versions of Python. Technically, `.*` matches an empty string, too, so `findall` duly finds one after the other match.

The simple workaround is to use a regex which matches more than zero characters.

```py
Pattern = re.compile('.+', re.DOTALL)
```

If you genuinely need to match empty strings, just not at the end of the string, you can add a(n ugly) lookahead assertion.

```py
Pattern = re.compile('(?!$).*', re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: I _think_ this should finally be fixed in 3.10 but I am not in a place where I can check right now.